# Android: Не работает notifyDataSetChanged в RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, recyclerview

Есть список чатов пользователя, и данные чата переодически обновляются. 
В service получаются данные, и отправляются во фрагмент. Когда данные получены фрагментом, они отправляются в адаптер, и тут начинается самое интересное. **Данные в адаптере не обновляются**

То есть они обновляются в ArrayList, но когда я вызываю notifyItemChanged(0);, первый item обновляться не хочет. Нужно сначала прокрутить вниз, а потом вверх, и уже тогда будут видны новые данные.

Код адаптера (не весь):

```
public class DialogAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DialogAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList items;
private ArrayList<String> dialogPosition;

public DialogAdapter(ArrayList items) {
    this.items = items;
    dialogPosition = new ArrayList();
    Dialog dialog;
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        dialog = (Dialog) items.get(i);
        dialogPosition.add(String.valueOf(dialog.ownerId));
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(App.context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_item, parent, false)
    );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    /* Code */
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    View itemView;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.itemView = itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        App.openChat((Dialog) items.get(getPosition());
    }
}

public void setMsg(String body, int chat) {
    int position = dialogPosition.indexOf(String.valueOf(chat));
    if (position != -1) {
        notifyItemMoved(position, 0);
        Dialog dialog = (Dialog) items.get(position);
        dialog.body = body;
        items.remove(dialog);
        dialogPosition.remove(String.valueOf(chat));
        items.add(0, dialog);
        dialogPosition.add(0, String.valueOf(chat));
        notifyItemChanged(0);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: У вас в данных идет удаление, потом вставка, а не изменение содержимого по позиции. Видимо `notifyItemChanged()` такое не воспринимает "на свой счет". Если есть желание, попробуйте не перемещать данные, а просто внести мзменения по позиции, если результат будет таким же, то нужно что то решать, иначе использовать другие методы нотификации о изменениях в данных.

Comment: я думаю проблема может быть в `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: @georgehardcore  onBindViewHolder не вызывается вообще

Comment: @pavlofff попробовал, не помогает. Какие ещё есть методы нотификации об изменениях?

Comment: А почему например items `ArrayList`, a не `ArrayList<Dialog>`, раз уж ничего не помогает

Answer (score 1):

`RecyclerView` очень странно работает с данными и их изменением.
Не работает, потому что объект не изменился, вы удалили и добавили другой объект. Вам стоит уведомлять о ваших действиях досконально.
`notifyItemRemoved(0)` в сочетании с `notifyItemInserted(0)` должны сработать.

Comment: Возможно более подойдет `notifyDataSetChanged()`, так как указанные вами методы включают довольно заметную анимацию исчезновения и появления айтема, то есть список будет заметно двигаться туда-сюда.

Comment: RecyclerView нужно быть настолько точным насколько можно. Зачастую notifyDataSetChanged не срабатывает. Можешь погуглить это.

Comment: Ваш метод не срабатывает